# CGI and MIME type octet-stream confusion in C++ code

Tags: c++, apache, http, cgi

I am trying to develop CGI C++ code to respond to the following request:

```
curl --data-binary @file.bin -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" 
     -X POST "http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/server.cgi"
```

*file.bin* is a binary file of size 4100 bytes.

On the server:

```
getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
```

correctly gives 4100. However when I do

```
char* post_data = new char[len+1]; //here len = 4100
cin.read(post_data, len);
```

or

```
fgets(post_data, len, stdin);
```

it only reads data until it sees char value **26**. I mean if the stream doesn't include decimal values **26** my code works if it does it treats **26** as a termination character.
I discovered it by wondering why it read only 214 bytes of real data.

I want to be able to send binary data to my server somehow, but am confused by this behaviour. 
Any clues?

It is all on Apache 2.4 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of false alert from my side.

If someone finds it helpful, this is my solution:

Under Windows for backward compatibility with DOS 26 (CTRl+Z) is read as EOF.
The problem will be only under Windows one can force to read data from cin as binary by:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
```

and add headers:

```
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <io.h>
```